# Is there a way to add "public" objects using django-guardian

Tags: django, django-guardian

I am using the great [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) to manage per object permissions on a project. In such project I will like all users be granted a permission (view, for instance) to all public objects.

As far as I know the only way to do this is granting each user the permission for each public object every-time an account is created.

Is there a better way such as leaving an object with a "wild card" permission or something similar. Is using a group the best?

Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a clean solution for this?

Comment: Not quite @JamieStrauss: I followed Leonardo's advice: A group is created for all users inside a migration, then a signal attached to user creation (activation)  makes every user a member of the group.

Comment: Thanks jdcaballerov, this ended up being the approach I took also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to assign all the users when created a `group` and provide access to the models with the default group in the definition of the model, as described here: https://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2/userguide/assign.html